# Access via ForeignKey to the image field of parrent model in QuerySet [Django]

Tags: python, django

I have this simplified `model.py`:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    description = models.CharField()

class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="product_images/")
    is_main = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

An `Product` can have many `ProductImage`, but only  `ProductImage` which has field `is_main=True` shall be rendered in a template together with all field of `Product`.

The following data set from the `views.py`:

```
products = Product.objects.all()
```

So now I would want to do something like this in the template:

```
{% for product in products %}
<img class="card-img-top" src="{{ product.productimage_set.filter(is_main=True).photo }}" alt="Card image cap">
<div class="card-body">
    <h4 class="card-title">{{ product.name }}</h4>
    <p class="card-text">{{ product.description }}</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
</div>
```

But obviously that's not possible. Not from the template directly, at least.

What is the proper way to get all the fields of `Product` and its image with attribute `is_main=True` inside the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest would be to keep the logic in the model and add a method or property

```
class Product(models.Model):
    # ...
    def main_image(self):
        return self.productimage_set.get(is_main=True)
        # or more robust:
        # return self.productimage_set.filter(is_main=True).first()
```

that you can access in the template:

```
 ... src="{{ product.main_image.photo.url }}  # don't forget the 'url'
```

Comment: @kotmsk I'd go with property or even better `cached_property` (from `django.utils.functional`). https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.functional